# how to get enum value from enum type?

Tags: c++, enums, c++03

The question in the title may sound trivial, so I better explain with some code what I want to do...

In C++11 I can do this:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace X {
    enum class  FOO { A,B };
}

template <typename T> void foo(T t) { 
    if (t == T::A) { std::cout << "A"; }
}

int main() {
    foo(X::FOO::A);
}
```

The important point here is that the template `foo` does not need to know in what namespace the enum is declared. I could as well call `foo(Y::FOO::B)` (provided there is a `enum class` called `FOO` in namespace `Y` having members `A` and `B`).

Now the question is: How to get the same with plain old enums (and only C++98 stuff)?

This works:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace X {
    enum FOO { A,B };
}

template <typename T> void foo(T t) { 
    if (t == X::A) { std::cout << "A"; }
}

int main() {
    foo(X::A);
}
```

but only because `foo` knows in what namespace the enum is declared. And it wont work for a `Y::FOO::B` ! (In C++11 it also works if I replace the line with `if (t == T::A) ...`, even with a plain `enum`)

**Is there a way to get this working in C++98/03 without refering to `X` in the template explicitly?**

For the sake of completeness, in C++98, this

```
template <typename T> void foo(T t) { 
    if (t == T::A) { std::cout << "A"; }
}
```

results in

```
error: ‘A’ is not a member of ‘X::FOO’
```

PS: I am not allowed to change the `enum` and the template has to live in a different namespace than the `enum`.

PPS: a simple `if (t == 0)` would probably work, but thats something I would like to avoid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add to [Nicol Bolas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45307907/27678), you can kind of hack your way to a solution using [ADL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl):

```
namespace X {
    enum FOO { A,B };
    bool IsA(FOO t)
    {
        return t == A;
    }
}

template <typename T> void foo(T t) { 
    if (IsA(t)) { std::cout << "A\n"; }
    else{std::cout << "not A\n";}
}
```

#### [Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/isjFKrVHfcEq2TX7)

Comment: unfortunately I cant add anything to `X`. However, I didnt expect it to be so diffucult, so I am happy about any suggestions / workarounds

Comment: @tobi303: "*unfortunately I cant add anything to X.*" Of course you can. C++ doesn't close namespaces (except for `std`, which is reserved). You can *always* inject whatever you want into whatever namespace you want.

Comment: @NicolBolas oh yes sure ;). The problem is that what is `X` in my question in reality is a couple of hundreds different namespaces, so I ruled that out without really thinking about it. Anyhow for my real problem I found a different workaround so there is no point in trying to explain it further. For the question as asked here, this is a nice solution.

Answer (score 6):

Until C++11, there was no way to say "the enumerator name within this enumeration". That's *why* it was added to C++11, even to unscoped enumerations.

Comment: and there is no way to somehow get the namespace from `T`?

Comment: @tobi303: That would require reflection, which we don't have, even in C++17.

Comment: ...but doesnt this mean that enums were pratically unusable as template parameters prior to C++11 ?

Comment: Unusable for what purpose? I can certainly make a `vector<EnumType>`. I can pass an enum value to any number of algorithms that take a value and do something with that value. What you *can't* do is pass an enum value to a function that is then going to compare it to a static enumerator. But that's quite rare; I've never had to do that.

Comment: unusable in the sense that you cannot refer to a value of the enum without knowing exactly where it is declared. Anyhow, thanks for the answer. I dont really like it, but I guess I will have to accept it ;)

Comment: Normally in C++98 I would use an additional nested namespace to simulate enum class, something like: `namespace FOO { enum Type { A, B }; }`